# CSS - HTML - 2 float columns

Tags: css, html, css-float

I've run into a problem.

My code now:

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
   <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;"><b><u>TEST</u></b></div>
   <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

And it seems like this now:

[image: IMG1]

When the word in the second div is as short as can be placed after the first div, it's in one row, like this:

[image: IMG2]

My goal is to get this design, when the decond div is longer. I'm not allowed to use `WIDTH` and `FLOAT: RIGHT` because the inner divs have to de dynamic!

Like this (PhotoShop):

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Note that you're missing the closing tag for your first `div`

Comment: #1 - it's not missing, just forgot to copy.
#2 - I can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you looking for

I removed the float:left from the second inner div and increased the margin.

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;"><b><u>TEST</u></b></div>
<div style=" margin-left: 60px; border: 1px solid black;">A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A     A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A       </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div></div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. :) didn't think on this.. :D

Comment: No problem.  Hope its does what you need.  Remember to check in other browsers as I only checked in Chrome and IE9

Comment: Good answer. Only problem is if the size of the 'test' div changes. Adding a `margin-right: 20px` to the 'test' div instead and adding `overflow: auto` to the second inner div does the trick. [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/pP3Mz/).

Comment: True - I also found that max-width will also do what he needs aswell.  but I'm not sure how the older IE browser support this

Answer (score 2):

No width allowed ? OK here is a try:

AFAIK you can't do that with float without having a few width properties. Same with relative positioning of a "column": you still need a width and margin-left on the second column.

A solution is using CSS `display: table;` and **`table-cell`** (nope, not HTML table ;) ). It's as flexible as you want.
**http://dabblet.com/gist/1717860** will show you an example (HTML is separated from CSS, an id was added for clarity but isn't really needed and deprecated element u was removed and b replaced by strong. But CSS `font-weight: bold;` would be better, without context)

```
#main {
  display: table;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#main > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  padding: 1em;
}


#main > div + div {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

EDIT: compatibility **IE8+**
`display: inline-block;` is a good fallback for IE6/7. Well display: inline; zoom: 1; in fact, as IE6/7 doesn't understand the inline-block value but can achieve the same with inline+hasLayout)

Comment: Without code, I can only tell you that whether children aren't displayed in table-cell mode or parent isn't displayed as a table. Or that your "cells" don't have the same parent (not ancestor, parent).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;width:50px;"><b><u>TEST</u></b></div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid black;width:420px;">A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

This is close to what you wanted. I just set the width for the inner div's. Also, you forgot to close the first div tag.

Comment: I believe WIDTHs were not allowed on the _inner_ DIVs, no?

Comment: Just forgot to copy, and I'm not allowed to use width!

Comment: @Skylineman I tried it and it looks like your Photoshop image

Answer (score 0):

Float the first box left and give it an fix width. Then give the right div a margin-left bigger than the left div's width! ... and do not float the second div

Comment: ... and do not float the second div, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black;">
   <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
     <b><u>TEST</u></b>
   </div>
   <div style="overflow: hidden;">
     <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid black;">A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmRY2/5/

Answer (score 0):

Is like a table cell, try this

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black;">  
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;"><b><u>TEST</u></b></div>
    </div>  

    <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <div style="margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A  </div>
    </div>

    <br style="clear: both;">
</div>
```